# error with exec() function in php

Tags: php, database, command-line, exec

I am having some issues running a program from a command line in php. Whenever I run the program in the command line, the proper file is created and it works perfectly. However when I go and put it in my php and use the exec() function, nothing happens.

In the end I want the user to be able to select the parameters he wants to run on the external program, but for now im just trying to run it with hard coded values in....

Here is the command that I use to run the program from the command line and its parameters.

```
 [path1] -p blastp -d [parameter1] -i [path2] -e [parameter2] -m 9 -o [path3]

 where [path1] is the path to ../blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall, 
       [path2] is the path to sample.fasta
       [path3] is the path for the output file (you may want to create another folder for generating the output)
       [parameter1] is the name of database chosen by the user from your page (eg. Human.db, Viruses.db, etc)
       [parameter2] is the E-value given by the user from your page(eg. 0.0001, 1, 1000, etc)
```

The actual code I would type into the command line would be

```
~/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall -p blastp -d db -i ~/temp/sample.fasta -m 9 -o output'
```

Here is my code so far.

```
<form method="POST", action="/~cs4380sp15grp4/home/blast.php">


<?php
    session_start();
    require_once '../secure/database.php';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

    if($mysqli->connect_error){
            exit('CON Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ' ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    //Insert the values into the database

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


            $db = $_POST['database'];
            $evalue = $_POST['evalue'];
            $sequence = $_POST['BlastSearch'];



             exec('/students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall -p blastp -d db -i /students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/temp/sample.fasta -m 9 -o /students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/temp/output');
    }





?>
```

So my exec function isnt working in my php page because that same command works in the terminal.

Comment: Stop posting the same question..

Answer (score 0):

Does the Apache server user have access to this program? To make sure, try to run `sudo chmod 755 /students/groups/cs4380sp15grp4/blast/blast-2.2.26/bin/blastall` and try again.

Likewise, make sure that the Apache process has access to the input and output directories.